# Find the roots $\sqrt{x+6}+\sqrt{x-1}=\sqrt{x+4}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I found the roots of the equation you get when you put in the second exponent the both sides: [image]

What should I do next? How to do the proof?

Comment: You have a mistake above, you should end up with a quadratic equation, the equation you have above ends up as a quartic. In any case, the roots you found are the roots of the 'correct' equation ($3x^2+18x-25=0$), however neither of these roots satisfy the original equation, so there are **no** solutions in the reals. You can see this by plotting.

Comment: As an alternative for proving it, you may want to try those values and behold that they are **not** the roots of this equation.

Comment: @copper.hat can you tell me why they don't satisfy it? It would be so helpful...I don't know how to make the sum or subtraction of square roots by replacing the equation roots.

Comment: Well, as Lab's answer below shows, there can be no real solutions for $x \ge 1$, and you require $x \ge 1$ for the equation to be well defined.

Answer (score 3):

For real $x\ge1$ $$\sqrt{x+4}-\sqrt{x+6}=\sqrt{x-1}\ge0$$

$$\iff\sqrt{x+4}\ge\sqrt{x+6}\iff x+4\ge x+6$$ which is impossible for finite $x$

Comment: what means is possible for finite x? Which is the solution? I need to do this exercise with the method I wrote on my question.

Comment: @user219242, For $\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{x+4}{x+6}=1$ There should be no solution in real

Comment: Please can you explain without limits, we haven't studied them yet. How can I do the proof with my solutions?

Comment: @user219242, As $6>4\iff x+6>x+4$ right?

Comment: it means, you should check the problem, probably you mistyped something...